# $x^3+Ax+B$ is not a square number but $x^3+Cx+D$ is a square

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, cubics

Determine 4 distinct $A, B, C, D$ for any rational $x$ such that

1. **either**  $x^3+Ax+B$ is not a square number but $x^3+Cx+D$ is a square.

**or,**

2. $x^3+Cx+D$ is not a square number but $x^3+Ax+B$ is a square.

What are the value of $A, B, C, D$? how to approach this problem?

this post is a consequence of [a previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3577496/how-to-make-x3axb-a-square-number)

Comment: How many different questions are being asked here, and is $x$ the same in all of them?

Comment: @IvanNeretin same question, if you don't have the solution atleast share some idea, that is the purpose of second question , and yes same $x$.

Comment: Not only I don't have a solution, but I don't even understand the problem. If (1) and (2) is the same question, then you literally require $x^3+Ax+B$ **to be** a square and **not to be** a square at the same time. How so?

Comment: @IvanNeretin edited the post plz see

Comment: Got it now, thanks. Have to think for a while.

Comment: What's the difference between the two questions.  Any answer to 1) is the answer to 2) with the labels reversed.  Also do $A,B,C,D$ need to be rational, integer?

Comment: Is the idea that there is one set of $A,B,C,D$ that works for _any_ rational $x$? And is the intention that the squares are integral, or can they be rational squares?

Comment: @fleablood you can not relabel, those are 4 distinct $A, B, C, D$

Comment: @StevenStadnicki  I don't know whether only one such set exists, but any set that satisfies the condition is okay to me

Comment: @Andrew It's still not clear what 'the condition' is. Am I given an $x$ and allowed to find a specific $A,B,C,D$ for that $x$? Or am I given nothing and expected to find an $A,B,C,D$ that will work regardless of what $x$ is plugged in?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki yes, regardless of what x is plugged in, and I have written in the post that any rational $x$

Comment: The problem is that the way you've phrased it in the post suggests that $A,B,C,D$ could depend on $x$. I would suggest saying 'find constants $A,B,C,D$ such that for any rational $x$, either...' etc. — that makes it clearer what the quantifiers are. Also, you haven't answered the second half of my question — is the expression $x^3+Ax+B$ supposed to be _integer_ and square, or is it supposed to be the square of a _rational_ number?

Comment: Also also: what's the origin of this problem? What is its motivation? Do you have any reason to believe that it's true?

Comment: Then I believe what you want is not possible, basically because you can only have so many integer points on an elliptic curve.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin it does not have to intger, the x is rational, plz check.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that earlier. But anyway, by being true for any rational $x$ this has to be true for any integer $x$ too, which in turn brings us to what I said about elliptic curves.

Comment: Related question (closed) on MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354806/squaring-a-cubic-equation